# How to get server side cookies value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

How to get server side cookies value from JavaScript.
Here I have declare cookies from server side

I want to check whether cookies are `null` or not.

The C# code:

```
String UserId = usrDT.Rows[0]["user_id"].ToString();
UserDAO.StorageCookies.myCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
UserDAO.StorageCookies.myCookie.Values.Add("userid", UserId);
UserDAO.StorageCookies.myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(UserDAO.StorageCookies.myCookie);
```

The JavaScript Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".edit-btn").click(function () {
        var cookies = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["myCookie"].Value';
        alert(cookies);
        var v = $(this).data("textval");
        var qid = $(this).data("ques-qid");
        var getResponce = "http://localhost:1234/Models/answer.aspx?q=" + qid;
     if (cookies != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: getResponce,
            data: {
                "Submit": "EditAnswer",
                "ans_id":v
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                var htmlEditor = $find("editAnswer_ctl02");
                htmlEditor.set_content(msg);
            }
        })
     } else {
         alert("elseCondition");
            $('.login-form').modal('show');
        }

    })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JavaScript is able to select `cookies` as `cookies` stored at clients browser, just use this function

```
function getCookie(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

   for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
   }

   return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include this small javascript library (~800 bytes gzipped!). 
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie It used to be a jquery plugin but it had very few dependencies on jquery so they made it its own stand alone library.

Read cookie:

```
<script src="/path/to/js.cookie.js"></script>

Cookies.get('name'); // => 'value'
Cookies.get('nothing'); // => undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use document.cookie , you can use cookie js which will help to get value of any key 
Please get js from https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie and see it's usage.