# How to get Cookie set with Response.SetCookie(cookie) from Asp MVC using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I have set my cookie in the login section like so:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("sys_user_id", (query.UserAccountId).ToString())
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
};
Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

I can access and change to integer the same cookie at the `view` using this code:

```
<script>
    var sysUserId = @Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["sys_user_id"].Value);
</script>
```

but if I put this in a .js file, I get error at `@Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["sys_user_id"].Value);`. It is because the .js file cannot read the razor syntax. Is there a way to get my "sys_user_id" cookie and convert it to an integer using javascript so I can place it in my .js file?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have not yet got the answer to this kind of question, this is how I did it.

I created a new function like so:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)===' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }

    return "";
}
```

then I called my "sys_user_id" cookie using this code:

```
var sysUserId = getCookie("sys_user_id);
```

This is the post for this answer:
[How to get server side cookies value in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357260/how-to-get-server-side-cookies-value-in-javascript/34357653)